# Regexp for web site url validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

How **to validate** by regular expression these urls:

```
http://123.12.12.124:1234/default.html
http://www.mysite.com
http://www.mysite.com/
https://www.mysite.com
anyProtocol://www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com
mysite.com
```

and

```
http://www.my.site.com/default.aspx
http://www.my.site.com/default
http://www.my.site.com/default/
anyProtocol://www.my.site.com/default.anyExtension
```

and

```
http://www.my.site.com
anyProtocol://www.my.site.com/
https://www.my.site.com
www.my.site.com
my.site.com
```

Comment: So, what have you tried yourself? Which part of your regex are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah. You have to have a start for yourself, no? We're not here to provide you with complete solutions to your problem. We're here to help you find answers to your specific issues. We're very happy to guide you, like Marthin below, but you will rarely find someone willing to just write up an entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to validate the URL yourself, have a look at the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class. If you try creating a `Uri` with an invalid address it should throw a `UriFormatException`. Quick example:

```
var valid = false;
try { 
    new Uri(someUrl);
    valid = true;
}
catch (UriFormatException) {}
```

This will be invalid if the scheme (`http://` part) isn't included though as it isn't a valid URI, so you should try to make the input URL sane first.

Comment: How to do this on client side? new System.Uri runs on server side.

Comment: @Alex, Please edit your question to add this new piece of information. It should have been there from the start. =)

Comment: You didn't say this in your question, you should be looking for a solution in JavaScript. You could use validate the URI client-side by using a server side service (using `System.Uri`). Try that and ask a new question if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build your own url rewrit engine in .NET then I would strongly recommend that you use the already existing products. Linke the built-in in IIS 7.

But otherwise, here a little hint on what you actuelly need to check for:

> http://123.12.12.124:1234/default.html

I would simply check that its an exakt match.

> http://www.mysite.com http://www.mysite.com/ https://www.mysite.com
>   anyProtocol://www.mysite.com www.mysite.com mysite.com

Since you say anyprotocol and even just mysite.com then i would check that mysite.com is in the url and that it dosnt have more then at most a "/" after the url.

> http://www.my.site.com/default.aspx http://www.my.site.com/default
>   http://www.my.site.com/default/
>   anyProtocol://www.my.site.com/default.anyExtension
>
> http://www.my.site.com anyProtocol://www.my.site.com/
>   https://www.my.site.com www.my.site.com my.site.com

Here you only need to check that the url contains my "my.site.com" and also add a (0,1) occurence of "default" since you dont rely care about the extension.